# Looking for .NET parser of shell output

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a library which is able to parse output of unix shell commands such as `ipadm`, `df` or `zpool`. Can someone help out?

Comment: Sound like you need to write your own text parser.  There is no library that will work for all shell commands.

Comment: Many shell commands return results in a fixed-width command. You don't need a special parser for that. You can use string manipulation commands either to split by space or read strings of a fixed length, just like you would in Linux. You could also use a Regex to parse each line

Answer (score 0):

Many shell commands return results in a fixed width format. This doesn't need any special parsing, simple string splitting or a regular expression is enough. For example the following regular expression can match the output of `df` :

```
^(?<fs>.{14})\s(?<blocks>.{9})\s(?<used>.{9})\s(?<available>.{9})\s(?<use>.{4})\s(?<on>.+)$
```

You can use this with [Regex.Matches(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse each line and extract each column as a named group:

```
var pattern = @"^(?<fs>.{14})\s(?<blocks>.{9})\s(?<used>.{9})\s(?<available>.{9})\s(?<use>.{4})\s(?<on>.+)$";
var regex=new Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.Multiline);

var matches=regex.Matches(screenOutput);
foreach (Match line in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",line.Groups["fs"].Trim(), line.Groups["used"].Trim());
}
```

or even

```
var results = from Match line in regex.Matches(screenOutput)
              let groups=line.Groups
              select new {
                            FS=groups["fs"].Value.Trim(),
                            Used=groups["used"].Value.Trim()
                         }

var actualValues=results.Skip(1); // Skip the header
foreach......
```

The regular expression captures fixed-width strings into named groups (fs, blocks, etc) which allows the code to access them through the `Groups` property. `^` and `$` match the start and end of a single line when `RegexOptions.Multiline` is used.